# Open solution in a directory symbolic link in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When using Visual Studio to open solutions under directory symbolic link, it will  be opened as a solution in the real folder, not the directory symbol link.
e.g.:

```
mklink /d <link folder> <real folder>
```

When open

```
<link folder>/1.sln
```

In Visual Studio, the opened solution will be

```
<real folder>/1.sln
```

This render the symbolic link useless.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed VS can open solution under directory symbol link, the problems is in the  open file dialog of VS. So the solution is command line, e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" <link folder>/1.sln
```